# Case Owner changing upon case insert (all case triggers are inactive)

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I'm trying to run a unit test to see if the case owner upon insertion matches an expected value. In this case, the expected case owner will be the account owner. However, upon inserting the case, the case owner changes to a queue. The queue in this case is our "default" queue, which is configured in the support settings module. I recently deactivated all of the triggers on the case object to see if the owner was changing after insert, but that does not seem to be the issue.

```
Test.startTest();

    CreateTicket obj = new CreateTicket();
    Case newCase = obj.createcase();
    System.debug('The owner on the new case is a user' + newcase.ownerid);
    Database.dmloptions dmo = new Database.DMLOPtions();
    dmo.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule = false;
    newcase.setOptions(dmo);
    insert newCase;
Test.stopTest();

String expectedOwner = 'Expected Owner';
String actualOwner = [SELECT Id, Ownerid FROM Case WHERE Id = :newCase.id LIMIT 1][0].owner.name
System.assertEquals(expectedOwner, actualOwner , 'owners do not match');
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Check your assignment rules

Comment: You should really assert on `OnwerId`, not that it makes much difference here. Perhaps you have a `Workflow Rule` in play?

Comment: Check your debug logs from running the test. Whatever is going on in should have a hint in the logs.

Comment: It may not be triggering any assignment rule, so is ending up with the default owner

Comment: Thanks for the feedback so far.
1. @SantanuBoral There is one assignment rule that points to the actual owner. However, the criteria for that rule should be caught when the case gets inserted.
2. Looked at some field updates on case object. There are some that update the owner field, but the value does not match the actual owner.

Comment: 3. @sfdcfox anything I should keep an eye out for in the debug logs? I have a user debug log, but doesn't really tell me much.

Comment: 4. @gorav I set the useFefaultRule to false. Ideally, it should not go through any assignment rules right?

Comment: Something to with OwnerId, I'd imagine. It might be assignment rules, workflow rules, process builder/flows, or apex code. Just anything that seems to be assigning the value. Try searching for the owner's ID in the debug logs, maybe something will show up.

Comment: @sfdcfox thanks. I'll keep searching through based on your suggestions. The strange thing here is that my "black box" test for creating this case seems to work as expected. I'm creating a case through the UI, and the case gets routed to the correct user. Make sense?

Comment: Came across a thread that appears to indicate running the test asynchronously is the only way to override assignment rules.  May be helpful here.  http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/132671/10062

Comment: why would you set `useDefaultRule = false`?  Since there can be only one active set of assignment rules; `useDefaultRule=true` makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the test apex execution runs in a different context than the developer console. For this to work through setup, I needed to ensure that the cases are routed through the assignment queues. Previously, the cases would be inserted and the owner would be the user who kicked off the test (me).