# Running a test in developer console v.s. setup

Tags: apex, unit-test, case, test-setup

I'm running a unit test in developer console and in setup and I appear to be getting two different results. Within the dev console, my unit tests appear to be passing. But when I run the tests in setup, the unit tests fail.

```
    @isTest 
    static void AssignCaseToIntegrationHCM() {

    String testCase1Owner, testCase2Owner, testCase3Owner;

    Test.startTest();

    Case testCase1 = [SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM Case WHERE Subject = :CASE_1_SUBJECT];
    Case testCase2 = [SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM Case WHERE Subject = :CASE_2_SUBJECT];
    Case testCase3 = [SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM Case WHERE Subject = :CASE_3_SUBJECT];

    testCase1Owner = getGroupNameById(testCase1.ownerid);
    testCase2Owner = getGroupNameById(testCase2.ownerid);
    testCase3Owner = getGroupNameById(testCase3.ownerid);

    Test.stopTest();

    System.assertEquals(HCM_QUEUE, testCase1Owner, 'Failed to assign case to HCM Queue');
    System.assertEquals(HCM_QUEUE, testCase2Owner, 'Failed to assign case to HCM Queue');
    System.assertEquals(HCM_QUEUE, testCase3Owner, 'Failed to assign case to HCM Queue');
 }

    private static String getGroupNameById(Id groupdId){
        return [SELECT Name FROM Group WHERE ID  = :groupdId LIMIT 1].name;
   }
```

For some reason, I get a queryexception when I call the **getGroupByName** method:

```
System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

See answer:
[Case Owner changing upon case insert (all case triggers are inactive)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/166747/case-owner-changing-upon-case-insert-all-case-triggers-are-inactive/184030#184030)

TL;DR - execution context is different, needed to use DML opts to ensure cases are routed correctly when running tests through setup