# Test method fails only when being run synchronously from the Dev Console

Tags: unit-test, developer-console, failing-tests, email2case

My test method will pass when "Always Run Ayschronously" is checked.  Test method will pass when being run through the UI.  Test method will pass when being deployed via ANT with `testLevel="RunLocalTests"`.

I have a custom Email To Case apex class.  This class handles incoming emails, creates Cases and assigns them to different Queues.

My test method is failing at an assert that checks a Case was assigned to a specific Queue.

It appears that when running via Dev Console synchronously the Case is assigned to the "Default Case Owner" specified in the Case Support Settings.

I have confirmed that in my test under all scenarios the Queue I want the Case to be assigned to, is set before the initial `insert` statement.

I haven't fully dug through all the logs, but I can't figure out why the Default Case Owner is being set when running via Dev Console, and only Synchronously?

---

Below is my Test Method

```
static testMethod void myTest()
{
    // create a new email and envelope object
    Messaging.InboundEmail email = new Messaging.InboundEmail() ;
    Messaging.InboundEnvelope env = new Messaging.InboundEnvelope();

    // setup the data for the email
    email.subject = 'Test Email ';
    email.fromname = 'FirstName LastName';
    email.plainTextBody = 'this is a test and only a test ';
    email.fromAddress = CONTACT_EMAIL;
    email.messageId = EMAIL_ID;
    List<String> mystr = new List<String>();
        myStr.add('dev@test.com');
        mystr.add('super.email@test.com');
    email.ccAddresses = mystr;

    Test.startTest();

        // call the email service class and test it with the data in the testMethod
        EmailToCaseProcessor emailProcess = new EmailToCaseProcessor();
        emailProcess.handleInboundEmail(email, env);

    Test.stopTest();

    Case myCase = [SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM Case WHERE Original_Email_From__c = :CONTACT_EMAIL LIMIT 1];

    Group queue = [SELECT Id, DeveloperName FROM Group WHERE DeveloperName = :CASE_Q_DEV_NAME LIMIT 1];

    // This assert only fails when running via
    // Developer Console with `Always Run Asynchronously` unchecked.
    System.assertEquals(queue.Id, myCase.OwnerId);
}
```

This is the bit of code in my Email To Case Processor that assigns ownership

```
if( !emailToEmailMappingMap.isEmpty() )
{
    Map<String, QueueSobject> queueDevNameMap = new Map<String, QueueSobject>();
    for(QueueSobject q :
    [
        SELECT Id, QueueId, Queue.DeveloperName
        FROM QueueSobject
        WHERE Queue.DeveloperName IN : setCaseOwner
        AND QueueId != null
    ])
    {
        queueDevNameMap.put(q.Queue.DeveloperName, q);
    }

    for(String emailAddress:  toCCAddress)
    {
        String caseOwner;
        if( emailToEmailMappingMap.containsKey(emailAddress.toLowerCase()) )
        {
            caseOwner = emailToEmailMappingMap.get(emailAddress.toLowerCase()).Case_Owner__c;
        }

        if( queueDevNameMap.containsKey(caseOwner) )
        {
            cas.Original_Email_To__c = emailAddress;
            cas.OwnerId = queueDevNameMap.get(caseOwner).QueueId;
            break;
        }
    }
}
System.debug( cas.OwnerId );// Output is 00Gd0000002KvMyEAK
insert cas;
```

The test fails and gives me this message

> System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: 00Gd0000002KvMyEAK, Actual: 00Gd0000001osK5EAI

At the time the Case record is inserted it has the OwnerId that I want it to have.  There is nothing in my trigger code that would re-assign it.  There are no Workflow Rules, or Process Builder, or Flows that would re-assign it.  There are no Case Assignment Rules that would assign it to the value `00Gd0000001osK5EAI`.

The only place that would assign it that value is the Default Case Owner in the Case Support Settings.

It is only ever assigned the `00Gd0000001osK5EAI` value when I run via Dev Console with `Always Run Asynchronously` unchecked.

Debug Log Data

> 16:32:38.582
>   (10952095870)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[642]|System.AssertException: Assertion
>   Failed: Expected: 00Gd0000002KvMyEAK, Actual: 00Gd0000001osK5EAI
>   16:32:38.582 (10952364953)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[642]|Bytes:78 16:32:38.582
>   (10952374607)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[642]|System.assertEquals(ANY, ANY)
>   16:32:38.582 (10952386195)|SYSTEM_MODE_EXIT|false 16:32:38.582
>   (10952452849)|FATAL_ERROR|System.AssertException: Assertion Failed:
>   Expected: 00Gd0000002KvMyEAK, Actual: 00Gd0000001osK5EAI
>
> Class.EmailToCaseProcessorTest.test_Regression_AssignToCCAddresses:
>   line 642, column 1 16:32:38.582
>   (10952461186)|FATAL_ERROR|System.AssertException: Assertion Failed:
>   Expected: 00Gd0000002KvMyEAK, Actual: 00Gd0000001osK5EAI

---

Update 4/13/2017: Adding this bit of code will cause the test to always assign to the "Default Case Owner" specified  in the Case Support Settings, whether it is run Synchronously or Asynchronously.  This is not desired.

```
Database.DMLOptions options = new Database.DMLOptions();
options.AssignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule = true;
cas.setOptions(options);
insert cas;
```

Changing `.useDefaultRule = false;` leaves me back where I started.  When run Asynchronously ownership stays with the Queue I've assigned, when run Synchronously it changes to the "Default Case Owner".

Comment: Let's see the code, please. Without it, it will be nearly impossible to help. Also, please include the error verbatim, or at least make it clear where the failure occurs.

Comment: @SebastianKessel  Code has been added.  Hope it helps

Comment: Just curious, are you using seeAllData=true? Also I noticed you are setting the email address value in your code to Original_Email_To__c. But the test method you are using Original_Email_From__c to query the Case. Could it be you are querying the wrong field?

Comment: @bobforce No, I am not using SeeAllData=true.  The Original_Email_To__c field captures the Email To address.  The Original_Email_From__c is captured from the Email From Address.  If I was querying the wrong field, the SOQL would fail.

Comment: Yeah just wanted to check. That's why I asked if you were using seeAllData, you could have had an existing record with the address you were querying so it would not have failed.

Comment: @dBeltowski Can you share the debug log from when it fails the assertion?

Comment: @DanielBallinger  I've added a section of the debug log where the test fails.

Comment: @dBeltowski I was more thinking that the SOQL query you showed in EmailToCaseProcessor isn't returning any rows (for some reason). Without that it wouldn't populate the map to then set the owner.

Comment: @DanielBallinger  You're right.  I just checked the debugs logs from Asynch vs Synch and Case.OwnerId is different just before insert.  I checked that earlier, and I thought it was the same.

Comment: @DanielBallinger OK, I'm going crazy.  Just checked my logs again.  Just before the `insert` statement the Case record has the exact same Owner Id.  Whether Asynch, or Synchronous.  Still one fails, the other doesn't.

Comment: @dBeltowski Does the [linked question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/113823/case-assignment-rule-is-always-executed-in-the-test-class) explain the behavior you are seeing?

Comment: @DanielBallinger I suppose it does.  The only difference from mine is that I'm setting `Case.OwnerId` in code before insert, while the linked question does not set `OwnerId` and relies on the system to do so.